# How to count duplicates in an array and cast the count in to the following format?

Tags: javascript

I've a collection of items.

```
items = [
{name: 'Thomas', id: '234234', 'job': 'painter'},
{name: 'Jonathan', id: '435123', 'job': 'driver'},
{name: 'Thomas', id: '234234', 'job': 'driver'},
{name: 'Mark', id: '767445', 'job': 'mechanic'},
]
```

What I want to achieve is that, I want to map the duplicate Count in the following manner.

Expected result structure:

```
duplicateCount = {
    id: {
        name: string;
        count: number;
    }
}
```

Where id is the user id from the above array(items), name is the name of the user and count is the duplication number.

**Here the duplication is counted based the id.**

Example:

```
duplicateCount = {
    234234: {
        name: 'Thomas',
        count: 2,
    },
    435123: {
        name: 'Jonathan',
        count: 1,
    },
    767445: {
        name: 'Mark',
        count: 1,
    },
  }


/******* explanation: here take one item ***********/
    234234: {
        name: 'Thomas',
        count: 2,
    },

  // 234234 is the user id & count is the duplication number.

/***********************************/

// we can ignore other props such as job. only two fields are required.
```

Suggest some ideas.

**UPDATE**
**SORRY I MISSED THAT ONE**

**UPDATE: Here the duplication is counted based the id.**

Please update the snippets.

Comment: what does not work?

Comment: You can't find the same id with differents names, can you ?

Comment: Sorry I missed that one. Duplication is counted based on user id.

Comment: If using reduce in a solution, *please explain why* / justify over a simpler loop. It does not naturally fit this problem in JavaScript and the examples show use side-effects: just use a normal looping approach expected to rely on side-effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reduce the array and check if `id` exists, then increment count or assign a new object.

```js
var items = [{ name: 'Thomas', id: '234234', 'job': 'painter' }, { name: 'Jonathan', id: '435123', 'job': 'driver' }, { name: 'Thomas', id: '234234', 'job': 'driver' }, { name: 'Mark', id: '767445', 'job': 'mechanic' }],
    counts = items.reduce((r, { name, id }) => {
        if (r[id]) r[id].count++;
        else r[id] = { name, count: 1 };
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(counts);
```

Comment: Why use reduce?

Comment: because it is self contained with the variables.

Comment: And the reading-complexity cost to separate out a variable is “more” than the cost to be wary of reduce performing side-effects (and having to return the same-object-modified accumulator)?

Comment: Well, at least a reason given, even if I disagree.. so vote for a possible implementation.

Comment: It’s not about performance. It’s cost of maintainability.. I work in large (and old) code, so jaded :/

Comment: Do you have a different suggestion? I would like to see that!!

Comment: Can you suggest the approach you feel better?

Comment: Please. It's a request.

Answer (score 1):

you can use reduce function

```js
const items = [
  {name: 'Thomas', id: '234234', 'job': 'painter'},
  {name: 'Jonathan', id: '435123', 'job': 'driver'},
  {name: 'Thomas', id: '234234', 'job': 'driver'},
  {name: 'Mark', id: '767445', 'job': 'mechanic'},
];

const output = items.reduce((acc, {id, name}) => {
  acc[id] ? acc[id].count++ : acc[id] = { name, count: 1 };
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(output)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

You can also use `forEach` loop

```js
const items = [
  {name: 'Thomas', id: '234234', 'job': 'painter'},
  {name: 'Jonathan', id: '435123', 'job': 'driver'},
  {name: 'Thomas', id: '234234', 'job': 'driver'},
  {name: 'Mark', id: '767445', 'job': 'mechanic'},
];

const res = {};
items.forEach(({name, id}) => (
  res[id] ? res[id].count++ : (res[id] = { name, count: 1})
));

console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I recommend a forEach or for, as reduce does not fit naturally with side-effects (a more reasonable use-case might be, eg, summing numbers). Not sure why everyone is proposing reduce as an optimal solution..

Comment: Do you have a different suggestion? I would like to see that!!

Answer (score 0):

you could achieve this with

```
const items = [
  { name: 'Thomas', id: '234234', job: 'painter' },
  { name: 'Jonathan', id: '435123', job: 'driver' },
  { name: 'Thomas', id: '234234', job: 'driver' },
  { name: 'Mark', id: '767445', job: 'mechanic' },
];

const duplicates = items.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const { id, name } = item;
  acc[id] = acc[id]
    ? { ...acc[id], count: acc[id].count + 1 }
    : { name, count: 1 };
  return acc;
}, {});
```

Comment: Why use reduce?

Comment: @user2864740 i think reduce will be more readable than a for loop, since the intent will be clear to what the reduction will be, also variables will be localised to the scope they are needed, and its easier to extract the reduce function into its own utility function. Also chaining will be easier with reduce, so many benefits over the regular for loop

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `Array.reduce()`:

```
let duplicateCount = items.reduce((accumulator, item) => {
    let id = item.id;
    if (!accumulator.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
        accumulator[id] = {
            name: item.name,
            count: 1
        };
    } else {
        accumulator[id].count++;
    }

    return accumulator;
}, {});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1r9todun/)

Comment: Why use reduce?

Comment: Do you have a different suggestion? I would like to see that!!

Comment: @user2864740 because it accomplishes the goal? Not sure what kind of answer you're looking for here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
let items = [
{name: 'Thomas', id: '234234', 'job': 'painter'},
{name: 'Jonathan', id: '435123', 'job': 'driver'},
{name: 'Thomas', id: '234234', 'job': 'driver'},
{name: 'Mark', id: '767445', 'job': 'mechanic'},
]

let dupCount = items.reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc[item.id] = {name: item.name, count: acc[item.id] ? acc[item.id].count + 1 : 1}

  return acc

}, {})

console.log(dupCount)
```

Comment: Why use reduce?